# Uploading File in Angular - Shows in req.body instead of req.files for nodejs Server

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, multer

In my nodejs api using multer as my middleware, I can see the postman post file requests in the request.file property, which of course then gets saved on my server. The request is send with the content type form-data. As soon as Save is hit on my controller, the file is already uploaded. All the details of the file(s) are in the request.files property

In Angular, the attached file is added to the body of the request, and my nodejs application cannot save the file as the middleware cannot see it. The imagedata is coming as base64 encoded string

I have tried setting the headers in angular to multipart/form-data, but I get a 500 error "Multipart: Boundary not found".

In Postman, if I remove form-data and set to none, it also does not work

#### Angular Component

```
  imageFile:any;

  onImagePicked(imageData: string | File) {
    if (typeof imageData === 'string') {
      try {
        /*this.imageFile = this.sharedService.base64toBlob(
          imageData.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', ''),
          'image/jpeg'
        );*/
        this.imageFile = imageData;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Err' + error);
        return;
      }
    } else {
      this.imageFile = imageData;
    }
  }

  savePhoto() {
    console.log ('Save');
    this.sharedService.uploadPhoto(this.imageFile).subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }
```

#### Angular Service

```
  public uploadPhoto(image: File) {
      //let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      //headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
      const imageData = new FormData();
      imageData.append('image', image);
      return this.httpClient.post(environment.apiURL + this.path, imageData);
      //return this.httpClient.post(environment.apiURL + this.path, imageData, {headers: headers});
  }
```

#### Nodejs Setup

```
 public express: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.express = express();

    this.setMiddlewares();
    this.setRoutes();
    this.catchErrors();
    this.setSocketServer();
  }

  private setMiddlewares(): void {
    this.express.options('*', cors());
    this.express.use(cors());
    this.express.use((reg, res, next) => {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 10000);
      next();
    });
    this.express.use(morgan('dev'));
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    this.express.use(helmet());

    const storageConfig = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, callback) => callback(null, './files'),
      filename: (req, file, callback) => callback(null, Date.now() + "-"  + file.originalname),
    });
    this.express.use(multer({storage: storageConfig}).any());

  }

  private setRoutes(): void {
    this.express.use('/api', api);
  }
```

#### Router for photos

```
import { Router } from "express";
import DfrPhotoController from "./dfrphoto.controller";

const dfrPhoto: Router = Router();
const controller = new DfrPhotoController();


dfrPhoto.post('/', controller.save);

export default dfrPhoto;
```

#### Controller to save

```
export default class DfrPhotoController {

    // TODO: link to the dfr
    public save = async (req:Request, res:Response): Promise<any> => {

        // Need to see files in request. File is already saved in 
        let files = req.files; 
        console.log (files);
        if (files === null || files === undefined ) {
            res.status(404).send({
                success: false,
                message:'No Files Found'
              });
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message:'Photo saved',
            data: files
          });
    }

}
```

I would like the angular file upload to work the exact same way as the postman example.  I do not mind the file writing as soon as I call save in the controller as I can add validation to the middleware.  If anyone has any ideas on this, I would be grateful

Sample Angular Send Request
[image]

Thanks

```
//Added Component using the image picker (html and ts)
//HTML
  <ion-grid>
    <form [formGroup]="form" >  
        <ion-row size="12">
            <ion-col  size-lg="6" size-xl="6" size="12"   size-md="12">
                <app-camera  (imagePick)="onImagePicked($event)"></app-camera>
                <!-- <ion-thumbnail>
                  <ion-img  width="200" height="200"  [src]="imageFile" ></ion-img>

                </ion-thumbnail>-->
                <img  [src]="imageFile"  >
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col  size-lg="6" size-xl="6" size="12"   size-md="12">
                <ion-label  position="floating">Photo Comments</ion-label>
                <!-- <ion-textarea rows="3" formControlName="rigComments"></ion-textarea>-->
                <ion-textarea rows="3" formControlName="photoComments"></ion-textarea>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-button (click)="savePhoto()">Save Photo</ion-button>
        </ion-row>
    </form>  
  </ion-grid>

//TS
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dfr-photo',
  templateUrl: './dfr-photo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dfr-photo.component.scss'],
})
export class DfrPhotoComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  sharedService: SharedService;

  constructor(sharedService: SharedService) {
      this.sharedService = sharedService;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      _id: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
      }),
      dfrId: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      photoComments: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      image: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur'
      })
    });
  }

  imageFile:any;

  onImagePicked(imageData: string | File) {
    if (typeof imageData === 'string') {
      try {
        /*this.imageFile = this.sharedService.base64toBlob(
          imageData.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', ''),
          'image/jpeg'
        );*/
        this.imageFile = imageData;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Err' + error);
        return;
      }
    } else {
      this.imageFile = imageData;
    }
    this.form.patchValue({ image: imageData });
    this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  savePhoto() {
    console.log ('Save');
    console.log(this.form.value.image);
    this.sharedService.uploadPhoto(this.form.value.image).subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }

}


// Image Picker Code - JS
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, EventEmitter, ViewChild, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins, CameraResultType, CameraSource, Capacitor} from '@capacitor/core';
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-camera',
  templateUrl: './camera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./camera.component.scss'],
})
export class CameraComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('filePicker') filePickerRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @Output() imagePick = new EventEmitter<string | File>();
  @Input() showPreview = false;
  selectedImage: string;
  usePicker = false;


  constructor( private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private platform: Platform) { }

  image2: SafeResourceUrl;

  ngOnInit() {
    if ( this.platform.is('desktop')) {
      this.usePicker = true;
    }
  }

  onPickImage() {
    if (!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Camera')) {
      this.filePickerRef.nativeElement.click();
      return;
    }
    Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 50,
      source: CameraSource.Prompt,
      correctOrientation: true,
      width: 300,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64
    })
      .then(image => {
        const image2: any = image; // to fix access to base64 data
        this.selectedImage = image2.base64Data;
        this.imagePick.emit(image2.base64Data);

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR ' + error);
        if (this.usePicker) {
          this.filePickerRef.nativeElement.click();
        }
        return false;
      });
  }

  onFileChosen(event: Event) {
    const pickedFile = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    if (!pickedFile) {
      return;
    }
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = () => {
      const dataUrl = fr.result.toString();
      this.selectedImage = dataUrl;
      this.imagePick.emit(dataUrl);// (pickedFile);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(pickedFile);
  }

}



// Image Picker Code - HTML
  <div class="picker">

    <ion-button color="primary" (click)="onPickImage()" *ngIf="!usePicker">
      <ion-icon name="camera" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Take Picture</ion-label>
    </ion-button>
  </div>
  <input
    type="file"
    accept="image/jpeg"
    *ngIf="usePicker"
    #filePicker
    (change)="onFileChosen($event)"
  />




// Sidenote - Example of sending directly from the form control (renamed to image)
onImagePicked(imageData: string | File) {
    if (typeof imageData === 'string') {
      try {
        /*this.imageFile = this.sharedService.base64toBlob(
          imageData.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', ''),
          'image/jpeg'
        );*/
        this.imageFile = imageData;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Err' + error);
        return;
      }
    } else {
      this.imageFile = imageData;
    }
    this.form.patchValue({ image: imageData });
    this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  savePhoto() {
    this.sharedService.uploadPhoto(this.form.value.image).subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }
```

Comment: How does the image picker work? If it uses `<input type="file"`, it is better to send the selected file directly. Sending a base64 data URL adds a needless 33% extra overhead.

Comment: I have also tried to sent the file directly. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the image data is coming on the server side into the request.body vs request.file.  I have even referenced multiple tutorials with no luck.  I can always get this to work with postman, but never with Angular 2+ . Please let me know if any other information could help.

Comment: List the ways you transmit the data on the client side and number them. Then list the ways you receive them on the server side and number them. Get a pair of dice, roll them. Use the number on one die to change the server side. Use the number on the other die to change the client side. Keep rolling and changing. With luck some combination will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May i suggest an alternative to Multer?

See below the weekly npm downloads:

> multer: 466,964
>
> formidable: 2,116,997

nodejs server:

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    form.parse(req)

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
        var path = __dirname + '/uploads'
        if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(path)
        }
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file) {
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
        res.send({ message: 'uploaded' })
    });
})
```

angular template:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileInput($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".JPG,.pdf,.doc,.docx">
```

angular component:

```
onFileInput(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    let file = fileList[0]
    console.log(file);
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/upload', formData).subscribe(
      res => console.log(res)
    )

  }
```

Comment: The FormData API uses base64 encoding to send files. Base64 encoding adds 33% extra overhead. It is better to send files directly.

Comment: thanks. did not know that. just wanted to provide fully working example to OP.

Comment: It seems crazy to base64 encode it on the client then base64 decode it on the server side when files can be sent and received in binary directly. It might work but it needlessly complicates things. Also it doesn't work well with really large files.

Comment: I updated the code to send the file in binary instead of the base64 encoded string.  Everything else worked with Multer once that change was done.  Thanks for taking the time to help plus providing a clear example.

Comment: The reason why I was using base64encode in the first place was for mobile devices to upload a picture from the Camera.  I am using Ionic with Capacitor, which I cannot see how to upload a jpeg.